# Warning: Unusual traffic from your computer. Why is this happening?

Tags: networking, internet

This warning keeps showing up and I have no idea why.
My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

> To continue, please type the characters below:
>
> About this page
>
> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This
> page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a
> robot. Why did this happen? IP address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Time:
> 2016-01-20T12:04:04Z URL:
> https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=AMOVA&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Can someone help me out?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you post the URL of the page that generated this message, as well as at least a synopsis of what you'd been doing just before seeing this message.

Comment: @ZeissIkon, honestly, everytime I submit something in Mozilla's searchbar this appears. This has been happening for a few days and I don't remember if I've might done a download with malicious software. This is really weird... but for sure I haven't downloaded software that wasn't from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: What's your default search engine set to?

Comment: My search engine is Google.

Answer (score 1):

From Google's "Why did this happen":

> This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the Terms of Service. The block will expire shortly after those requests stop.
>
> This traffic may have been sent by malicious software, a browser plug-in, or a script that sends automated requests. If you share your network connection, ask your administrator for help — a different computer using the same IP address may be responsible. Learn more
>
> Sometimes you may see this page if you are using advanced terms that robots are known to use, or sending requests very quickly.

So, apparently your are (most likely) searching items or in a way that Google interprets as a search a robot is likely to use.  As noted, the flag should expire after your flagged activity stops (say, you quit using Google for a while).

Comment: But that's just weird because nothing in my method of searching or using web browse changed. And I'm just an inoffensive grad student... I haven't done nothing suspicious... and by the way, I saw that note you inserted here.

Comment: What Google detects automatically may not seem to you like anything suspicious.  They also mention using search terms 'bots are likely to use; I'm going to guess, assuming you're malware free (not necessarily a safe assumption), that that's the real issue.